# Laravel path from Controller to a file

Tags: laravel, path, controller

I am trying to implement payment by card in a laravel project. For this i neeed to make a link in Controller to a certificat file. 
I put the file in public/files and i made a variable like this

```php
$x509FilePath   = '/files/public.cer';
```

When i'm trying to encrypt an object using this file i get the error

```
Error while loading X509 public key certificate! Reason:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to reference the file path using the [helper public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path)

Try using:

```
$x509FilePath   = public_path('/files/public.cer');
```